How My Management (Cloud0) knows route to devices connected to my router on EVE-NG

The issue is like the following:
If I ping www.google.com from the VPC:
Ping goes to the gateway 10.0.0.1.
In the routing table of R1 the default route is through 192.168.52.2.
Ping travels to 192.168.52.2 then gets NATed and goes to the Internet.
After receiving the reply, the reply gets NATed back to the inside local address 10.0.0.2. Here I don't understand is how 192.168.52.2 is able to know the route to 10.0.0.0 network and send it through R1 when no static route is configured.

You mean / sure there's no NAT on R1 / at e0/0?

no nat configuration on R1, when I capture traffic using wireshark I can see the 10.0.0.2 direclty on VMnet8 adapter
